# Embedding LEFT in an AVERAGEIFS formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, formula

Hi I'm trying to use an AverageIFS formula to work out the average performance by month and by territory but I'm struggling to get it to work.

I can get it to work as individual IF functions but together it's just returning #VALUE!

The formula seen in cell C28 is `=AVERAGEIFS(2:25,BDPercentage[[#All],[Territory]],$B28,2:2,LEFT(C27,3)&"*")`

See in Cell C30 I manage to get it to Average just the Januarys for the first line of the table using this code `=AVERAGEIF(2:2,LEFT(C27,3)&"*",3:25)`, although even that is just returning the top line of the table when I would have thought it would average all the data available for January?[image]

NOTES:
The table in the screenshot is called "BDPercentage"
Row 2 consists of Date fields

Comment: 'Unlike the range and criteria arguments in the AVERAGEIF function, in AVERAGEIFS each criteria_range must be the same size and shape as sum_range.'  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690 So you just get an error if the ranges don't match with AverageIfs, but with Averageif there's a slicing behaviour https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642 So what I'm trying to say is that you need another approach, maybe index/match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: your primary objective:

> "*work out the average performance by month and by territory*"

Format your date headers as date i.e.:

```
=DATE(2020,1,1)
```

[image: Date formatted headers]

(day is irrelevant)

Next, use following formula to calculate averages (lot's of different ways, this is but one of them...which works as intended):

```
=LET(x_,(MONTH($E$3:$W$3)=COLUMNS($E14:E14))*($D$4:$D$10=$D14),SUM($E$4:$W$10*x_)/SUM(1*x_))
```

[image: Calculating average by row and column criteria]

Caveat: the `let` function reqiures Office 365 compatibility; if you have an older version of Excel then omit the let function and substitute `x_` with `(MONTH($E$3:$W$3)=COLUMNS($E14:E14))*($D$4:$D$10=$D14)`...i.e. two substitutions...

RE: using `averageifs` - @Tom Sharpe appears to have addressesd suitability in commentary.  If your objective is fixated upon using averageifs to get this to work then (notwithstanding a use case) - you can still use `averageifs` but would need to include an `index` or `filter` within to ensure dimensionality consistent between criteria and value ranges...

Comment: Thanks very much JB. A well written answer :)

Comment: ta - glad it helped.  keep well.